# adb can not access "multirom" directory

Tags: adb

i use cm11 in my nexus 5, and had installed multirom.

but i can not access it' directory, neither with adb nor with root filemanager.

below shows adb results.

```
root@hammerhead:/sdcard # cd multirom/                                         
root@hammerhead:/sdcard/multirom # ls
opendir failed, Permission denied
255|root@hammerhead:/sdcard/multirom # su
root@hammerhead:/mnt/shell/emulated/0/multirom # ls
opendir failed, Permission denied
255|root@hammerhead:/mnt/shell/emulated/0/multirom # cd ..
root@hammerhead:/mnt/shell/emulated/0 # ls -l|grep multirom
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          1970-05-28 17:00 multirom
root@hammerhead:/mnt/shell/emulated/0 # id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) context=u:r:init:s0
root@hammerhead:/mnt/shell/emulated/0 # ls /data/data/supersu/                 
system
```

only this directory is "1970-05-28 17:00", too strange.

i try touch, but no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think with a chmod you can do it.

```
su
```

And then

```
chmod 777 multirom
```

Hit thanks if helped.